# iOS: Performance of UIView animations vs CABasic/CAKeyframe animations

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer, uiviewanimation, caanimation

Is there a difference in the performance of UIView animation vs CA Animation blocks? I understand they are all interfaces to Core Animation, but am looking to squeeze the most performance vs resources per animation. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to benchmark them yourself to be sure, but my guess is there will be *no* difference. They are both using the same code under the covers and UIView and CALayers perform almost identically to each other. You'll get more performance by making sure you're handling alpha properly. Make everything opaque that can be. The less that has to be calculated through compositing the more responsive your animations will be.

Best regards.